# Springboot Maven Resource filtering for application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a SpringBoot project ( maven / java 8 ).

I want to filter some custom variables in src/main/resources/***application.properties*** by Maven
profile ( *dev.properties* | *prod.properties* )

The problem is after compilation in *target/MyApp/WEB-INF/classes/application.properties* is still the same and not filtered

***Maven command:***

```
mvn clean package -Pdev
```

***application.properties :***

```
b.token = ${origin.token}
```

***dev.properties :***

```
origin.token = OixxxxxeyJhbGciOiJIiY3ODkwopsdbuerfazdf
```

***prod.properties :***

```
origin.token = epbeoebbrtrryiterzerfeciIxxxxxxxibmFtZS
```

***pom.xml :***

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <env>dev</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <env>prod</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <filters>
        <filter>src/main/conf/filters/${env}.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: have you heard about spring profiles?

Comment: Maven profiles are the wrong way. Use spring profiles for that... see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.profiles apart of that tokens usually do not belong into property files or profiles should be provided from outside....

Comment: Thank you I will try to implement the spring profiles as a solution, but as you said maven profiles is an outdated way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked for me, you can choose your profile from Maven -P argument:

***Maven command:***

```
mvn clean package -Pdev
```

***application.properties :***

```
    #Active Profile
spring.profiles.active = @mainprofile@
```

***dev.properties :***

```
origin.token = OixxxxxeyJhbGciOiJIiY3ODkwopsdbuerfazdf
```

***prod.properties :***

```
origin.token = epbeoebbrtrryiterzerfeciIxxxxxxxibmFtZS
```

***pom.xml***

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <mainprofile>dev</mainprofile>
            </properties>
        </profile>

<!-- Do the same for prod profile here -->   
</profiles>
```